# Delete Polygon from Leafletmap R/Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, polygon, polygons

I draw a Polygon on a leafletmap which I use in a shiny app.
Everytime an event is fired I want to delete the old polygon and draw the new one over it.
That does not work - I assume I use `layerId` wrong?

Any hints on this?

```
# draw polygons
observeEvent(da$ar, {
    # remove polygon
    removeShape(map, layerId = unique(10))

    leafletProxy("myMap") %>% addPolygons(data = da$ar, stroke = TRUE, 
    fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    layerId = unique(10)
    )
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, I go it.
When you use a layer ID on an object and draw the same object with that layerID again, the object gets deleted.

So, that is enough:

```
 observeEvent(da$ar, {
    leafletProxy("myMap") %>% addPolygons(data = da$ar, stroke = TRUE, 
    fillOpacity = 0.5, smoothFactor = 0.5,
    layerId = "foo"
    ) 
 })
```

Comment: Also, for future references you can do it as "leafletProxy("myMap") %>% removeShape(layerId )  %>% addPolygons( ...) "